# SQL query for non duplicate records

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm attempting to build a query that will return all non duplicate (unique) records in a table.  The query will need to use multiple fields to determine if the records are duplicate.

For example, if a table has the following fields; PKID, ClientID, Name, AcctNo, OrderDate, Charge, I'd like to use the AcctNo, OrderDate and Charge fields to find unique records.

Table

```
PKID-----ClientID-----Name-----AcctNo-----OrderDate-----Charge
1        JX100        John     12345      9/9/2010      $100.00
2        JX220        Mark     55567      9/9/2010       $23.00
3        JX690        Matt     89899      9/9/2010      $218.00
4        JX100        John     12345      9/9/2010      $100.00
```

The result of the query would need to be:

```
PKID-----ClientID-----Name-----AcctNo-----OrderDate-----Charge
2        JX220        Mark     55567      9/9/2010       $23.00
3        JX690        Matt     89899      9/9/2010      $218.00
```

I've tried using SELECT DISTINCT, but that doesn't work because it keeps one of the duplicate records in the result.  I've also tried using  HAVING COUNT = 1, but that returns all records.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` will work if you only include the fields in the `GROUP BY` that you're using to find the unique records. (i.e. not `PKID`, but you can use `MAX` or `MIN` to return that since you'll only have one record per group in the results set.)

Comment: OK, I ran the query again using COUNT = 1 and it worked!  For some reason when I ran it before, it returned all records.  Thanks for the nudge it the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT   MAX(PKID)     AS PKID    ,
         MAX(ClientID) AS ClientID,
         MAX(Name)     AS Name    ,
         AcctNo                   ,
         OrderDate                ,
         Charge
FROM     T
GROUP BY AcctNo   ,
         OrderDate,
         Charge
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
```

or

```
SELECT PKID      ,
       ClientID  ,
       Name      ,
       AcctNo    ,
       OrderDate ,
       Charge
FROM   YourTable t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
       FROM    YourTable t2
       WHERE   t1.PKID     <> t2.PKID
       AND     t1.AcctNo    = t2.AcctNo
       AND     t1.OrderDate = t2.OrderDate
       AND     t1.Charge    = t2.Charge
       )
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply add:

```
GROUP BY AcctNo, OrderDate, Charge
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

The `GROUP BY` groups all rows with the same AcctNo, OrderDate and Charge together,
then the `HAVING COUNT(1) = 1` shows only the rows where there was just 1 progenitor.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks kekekela for the nudge in the right direction.

Here's the query that produced the result I wanted:

```
SELECT AcctNo, OrderDate, Charge FROM Table1 GROUP BY AcctNo, OrderDate, Charge
HAVING (COUNT(AcctNo) = 1) AND (COUNT(OrderDate) = 1) AND (COUNT(Charge) = 1);
```

Or more simplified based on Gus's example:

```
SELECT AcctNo, OrderDate, Charge FROM Table1 GROUP BY AcctNo, OrderDate, Charge
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just drop the `PKID` to return all records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
           ClientID
         , Name
         , AcctNo
         , OrderDate
         , Charge
FROM       table;
```

---

**Note:** 
This is slightly different from what you're asking.
It returns a unique set by removing the one non-unique field.
By your example, you're asking to return non-duplicates.

I could only see your example being useful if you're trying
to clean up a table by extracting the "good" records.

Answer (score 1):

Use window function for count and then you don't have to aggregate fields

```
select * from
(SELECT *,
count(*) over (partition by CLIENTID) as [Count]
from Table) t1
where t1.Count=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the non-unique records first, and then test for those records not in that set - like this

```
select * from mytable where pkid not in
(select t1.pkid 
from mytable t1 inner join mytable t2
on t1.pkid <> t2.pkid
and t1.acctno = t2.acctno
and t1.orderdate = t2.orderdate
and t1.charge = t2.charge)
```

the last part of the inner query lets you fiddle with the criteria for "equality" - add the required number of columns to test.
Of course, this gets a lot more interesting without that primary key :) In such cases I usually end up creating one

Ketil

Comment: Shouldn't the query read `>` or `<` instead of `<>`? With `<>`, the result will contain *none* of the duplicated rows instead of just one copy

Comment: No, the <> ensures you do not test a record against itself - same as Martin Smiths solution #2. A < or > would only look for duplicates on pkids with higher or lower pkid values - not enough to ensure uniqueness of the data columns specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT GMPS.gen.ProductDetail.PaperType, GMPS.gen.ProductDetail.Size FROM
 GMPS.gen.ProductDetail GROUP BY GMPS.gen.ProductDetail.PaperType,
 GMPS.gen.ProductDetail.Size
 HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (  
    EmployeeID CHAR(1),  
    FirstName VARCHAR2 (20),  
    LastName VARCHAR2 (20),  
    Salary NUMBER (8,2),  
    JoiningDate DATE,  
    Department VARCHAR2 (10),  
    Gender VARCHAR2 (6) 
);
```

Insert some values

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('1', 'Vikas', 'Ahlawat', 60000.00, '15-Feb-2013', 'IT', 'Male');  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('2', 'nikita', 'Jain', 53000.00, '09-Jan-2014', 'HR', 'Female');  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('3', 'Ashish', 'Kumar', 100000.00, '09-Jan-2014', 'IT', 'Male');  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('4', 'Nikhil', 'Shama', 48000.00, '09-Jan-2014', 'HR', 'Male');  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('5', 'anish','kadian', 50000.00, '09-Jan-2014', 'Payroll', 'Male');
```

-- To find a unique department name from the above-given table (Employee)

```
SELECT Department FROM Employee  
GROUP BY Department  
HAVING COUNT(Department) = 1;
```

- The above-given code should give you the only unique department name, 'Payroll'

You can try the code above to find unique data from other fields as well by editing a little. For instance;

```
SELECT Gender FROM Employee  
GROUP BY Gender  
HAVING COUNT(Gender) = 1;
```

should give you 'Female' as it is used only once in Gender field.